# Floated images stacked

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create a list of actors in a film with a small profile image to the left of the actor's name and their accompanying character, however my images are strangely stacking on top of one another, and I'm not sure why. The cast names, their character and the image are all being pulled in dynamically from an external API.

Below is an image of the current layout:
[image: Current layout]

The accompanying HTML and CSS is below:
**HTML**

```
<?php
    foreach($tmdb_cast['cast'] as $castMember){
        if ($tmp++ < 10)
            echo '<img src="http://cf2.imgobject.com/t/p/w45' . $castMember['profile_path'] . '" class="actor_image" alt="' . $castMember['name'] . '" title="' . $castMember['name'] . '" />';
            echo '<p>' . $castMember['character'] . ' - ' . $castMember['name'] . '</p>';
    }
    echo '<p id="morecast"><a href="http://www.imdb.com/title/' . $imdb_id . '/fullcredits" alt="View full cast list on IMDb">[...view all cast]</a></p>'
?>
```

**CSS**

```
#cast {
    margin-left: 50%;
    border: solid 1px red;
}

.actor_image {
    float: left;
}

#morecast {
    text-align: right;
}
```

The layout I'm trying to achieve is something similar to the one on display at IMDb, with the actor's name and character vertically aligned with the image:
[image: Wanted layout]

Comment: Thanks to post editor for improving code formatting - I'm new to Stack and haven't quite got to grips with how to best format code automatically!

Comment: You will get better answers if you post your actual HTML - not the PHP.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you're floating your images, but not applying a "clear" between your image+text units.  Try applying a "clear: both;" between each actor instance?

Comment: Thanks for this - it's got the images stacking one below the other now, which is perfect, however I'm wanting to place the actor name and their character next to the image, as on the IMDb example I've shown in the original post, and "clear: both" is placing it below the image.

Comment: You can apply float: left; to the text element as well, and put the clear beneath it.

Something like this:
html:
<img class="actor_image"></img><div class="actor_text">actor txt</div>

CSS: 
.actor_image, .actor_text { /* where actor_text is your new class */
    float: left;
}
.actor_clear {
  clear: both;
}

(sorry about the multiple edits; still working out how stackoverflow formats comments)

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the image and p elements in a div and have clear:both on the div.  Set the inline style to a class.  I did it inline as a quick-and-dirty example.

```
foreach($tmdb_cast['cast'] as $castMember){
    if ($tmp++ < 10)
        echo '<div style="clear: both;">'
        echo '<img src="http://cf2.imgobject.com/t/p/w45' . $castMember['profile_path'] . '" class="actor_image" alt="' . $castMember['name'] . '" title="' . $castMember['name'] . '" />';
        echo '<p>' . $castMember['character'] . ' - ' . $castMember['name'] . '</p>';
        echo '</div>'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'ts convenient to create a css class that wraps every image and text group:

```
echo '<div class="actor">
         <img src="http://cf2.imgobject.com/t/p/w45' . $castMember['profile_path'] . '"      class="actor_image" alt="' . $castMember['name'] . '" title="' . $castMember['name'] . '"   />';
echo     '<p>' . $castMember['character'] . ' - ' . $castMember['name'] . '</p>
      </div>';
```

And float each container

```
.actor{
    float:left;
    clear: left;
}
```

Now you have a box arround the image+text group that you can float. If this doesn't fix the problem, next step is define the `.actor`   "width" property